# Count the number of mismatches between two arrays

Tags: c, array, iteration, simd, sse

This function may compute the amount of unequal elements of two `char`-arrays of the length n:

```
size_t difference(size_t n, const char a[n], const char b[n]) {
    size_t res = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        res += a[i] != b[i];
    return res;
}
```

How can I make the iteration faster regarding the memory allocation of the arrays and the caches? Is there a way to use SSE intel intrinsics?

**EDIT:**

This is a standalone program which may run with as less processor cycles as possible without using compiler directives/pragmas.

Comment: We can't optimize code out of context. To be able to optimize code we need to see many of the function to see where the bottlenecks might be. This question is lacking any kind of code context. Why do you want to optimize this code? Are you compiling -O3 which should give you the best optimization?

Comment: Code Review is very different from Stack Overflow, we don't want to see the minimum reproducible code. We need to see more code to understand the problem you are trying to solve so that we can make meaningful suggestions. Please read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Although a source file containing only a single function can be complete. I think questions should at least provide a code listing that compiles.  Here, all you would need to add is the line `#include <stddef.h>`. In this specific case, it would be good to also add a test driver showing the intended use—particularly as the compiler will, in the real world, inline this function. So you will only see the generated code as part of a test driver.

Comment: @pacmaninbw "To be able to optimize code we need to see many of the function to see where the bottlenecks might be." Why are the users below able to do so then? "We need to see more code to understand the problem you are trying to solve so that we can make meaningful suggestions." Do you not find the answers below to have meaningful suggestions?

Comment: @pacmaninbw: The fact that they're asking about vectorizing it with SIMD implies that their expected `n` is significantly larger than 16, or is exactly 16 or 32 or something.  That's sufficient to describe the problem they're trying to vectorize.  It's not a good code-review question since what they actually want is different code, not commentary on this code.  (They're asking for intrinsics, not just tweaks to this to help compilers auto-vectorize if that's possible.)

Comment: But it is answerable as a Stack Overflow question (which they unfortunately cross-posted as [How to optimize array iteration in C for intel processors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76446245) with an identical question body).  And in fact already has been answered as [Can counting byte matches between two strings be optimized using SIMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15598997) (`mismatches = n - matches`)

Comment: @PeterCordes "It's not a good code-review question since what they actually want is different code, not commentary on this code." Can be a little gray around [performance questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7321), and [vectorization is somewhat debated](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8789). But I do find the argument to be much more compelling.

Comment: @Peilonrayz: Interesting.  I posted an answer on [Are vectorization requests on-topic?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10877)

Comment: @Peilonrayz The answer by Davislor is a serious attempt at a code review. The answer by harold is not a code review it is a discussion about assembly code specific to Intel processors. The way this question was asked would lead to discussions about assembly code and not code reviews of a C program.

Comment: @pacmaninbw You've evaded my questions. You've also brought up a point which isn't related to MRC -- what you closed the question for.

Answer (score 8):

At first I wasn't going to do this, in part because of the [cross-posted version of this question to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76446245/how-to-optimize-array-iteration-in-c-for-intel-processors) being closed as duplicates of various pre-existing questions about counting bytes, but I changed my mind..

### Actually making it fast

Auto-vectorization takes a big L in this case. Which compiler is used and which ISA level is targeted re-rolls the dice, but none of the results that I've seen are anywhere near "good". The common theme is that all compilers (at this time) get super hung up on `res` being 64-bit, while the key to doing this efficiently is avoiding 64-bit additions as much as possible - not because they're slow, but because a vector of any given size fits 8 times fewer 64-bit integers in it compared to 8-bit integers.

So with auto-vectorization, we end up with code like this: (from ICX, with `-O3 -march=haswell` - not allowing it to use AVX512, because that's not very widespread yet, but allowing it to use AVX512 just makes it do *other* silly things that are still hyper-focused on 64-bit operations for no good reason).

```
.LBB0_6:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        vmovdqu xmm6, xmmword ptr [rsi + rax]
        vpcmpeqb        xmm6, xmm6, xmmword ptr [rdx + rax]
        vpxor   xmm6, xmm6, xmm1
        vpmovzxbw       ymm6, xmm6              # ymm6 = xmm6[0],zero,xmm6[1],zero,xmm6[2],zero,xmm6[3],zero,xmm6[4],zero,xmm6[5],zero,xmm6[6],zero,xmm6[7],zero,xmm6[8],zero,xmm6[9],zero,xmm6[10],zero,xmm6[11],zero,xmm6[12],zero,xmm6[13],zero,xmm6[14],zero,xmm6[15],zero
        vpmovzxwd       ymm7, xmm6              # ymm7 = xmm6[0],zero,xmm6[1],zero,xmm6[2],zero,xmm6[3],zero,xmm6[4],zero,xmm6[5],zero,xmm6[6],zero,xmm6[7],zero
        vpmovzxdq       ymm8, xmm7              # ymm8 = xmm7[0],zero,xmm7[1],zero,xmm7[2],zero,xmm7[3],zero
        vpand   ymm8, ymm8, ymm3
        vpaddq  ymm0, ymm8, ymm0
        vextracti128    xmm7, ymm7, 1
        vpmovzxdq       ymm7, xmm7              # ymm7 = xmm7[0],zero,xmm7[1],zero,xmm7[2],zero,xmm7[3],zero
        vpand   ymm7, ymm7, ymm3
        vpaddq  ymm2, ymm2, ymm7
        vextracti128    xmm6, ymm6, 1
        vpmovzxwd       ymm6, xmm6              # ymm6 = xmm6[0],zero,xmm6[1],zero,xmm6[2],zero,xmm6[3],zero,xmm6[4],zero,xmm6[5],zero,xmm6[6],zero,xmm6[7],zero
        vpmovzxdq       ymm7, xmm6              # ymm7 = xmm6[0],zero,xmm6[1],zero,xmm6[2],zero,xmm6[3],zero
        vpand   ymm7, ymm7, ymm3
        vpaddq  ymm4, ymm4, ymm7
        vextracti128    xmm6, ymm6, 1
        vpmovzxdq       ymm6, xmm6              # ymm6 = xmm6[0],zero,xmm6[1],zero,xmm6[2],zero,xmm6[3],zero
        vpand   ymm6, ymm6, ymm3
        vpaddq  ymm5, ymm5, ymm6
        add     rax, 16
        cmp     rax, r8
        jbe     .LBB0_6
```

All of this is to compare and count two blocks of 32 bytes.

With the techniques mentioned on Stack Overflow, you could do it like this: (not tested)

```
size_t difference_avx2(size_t n, const char a[n], const char b[n]) {
    size_t i;
    __m256i count = _mm256_setzero_si256();
    for (i = 0; (i + 4095) < n; i += 4096) {
        __m256i inner_count = _mm256_setzero_si256();
        for (size_t j = 0; j < 4096; j += 32) {
            __m256i A = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)&a[i + j]);
            __m256i B = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)&b[i + j]); 
            __m256i comparemask = _mm256_cmpeq_epi8(A, B);
            inner_count = _mm256_sub_epi8(inner_count, comparemask);
        }
        count = _mm256_add_epi64(count, _mm256_sad_epu8(inner_count, _mm256_setzero_si256()));
    }
    for (; (i + 31) < n; i += 32) {
        __m256i A = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)&a[i]);
        __m256i B = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i*)&b[i]); 
        __m256i comparemask = _mm256_abs_epi8(_mm256_cmpeq_epi8(A, B));
        count = _mm256_add_epi64(count, _mm256_sad_epu8(comparemask, _mm256_setzero_si256()));
    }
    size_t count_scalar = _mm256_extract_epi64(count, 0) +
        _mm256_extract_epi64(count, 1) +
        _mm256_extract_epi64(count, 2) +
        _mm256_extract_epi64(count, 3);
    for (; i < n; i++) {
        count_scalar += a[i] == b[i];
    }
    return n - count_scalar;
}
```

The key trick is creating an extra inner loop, which runs 128 times (we could go up to 255 but it's such a non-round number.. but do it if you want). In that loop, we are free to subtract (or add) the boolean results *as bytes*, which prevents the 8x expansion factor that converting them to 64-bit numbers entails, and everything that comes along with it (the extra `vpmovzx`'s and so on).

The `_mm256_sad_epu8` trick to horizontally add groups of 8 bytes is just a bonus really, it doesn't get executed all that often.

Is it fast? [quick-bench says yes](https://quick-bench.com/q/N4xo-vup4sqAriNrHMVIZG0uaFU). Unfortunately the disassembly of the AVX2 version broke, but I'm inclined to believe the result: it *should* be about 8x as fast as what Clang was doing itself, because we don't have the 8x expansion factor. That's a bit simplistic and frankly optimistic, but still, this result does not imply that the benchmark is broken, it really could be that much faster.

If you cannot use AVX2, you should be easily able to cut this down into an SSSE3 version with 128-bit vectors.

---

It's possible to some extent to trick compilers into doing (almost) the right thing, by implementing the "separate inner loop" idea in scalar code, and then relying on auto-vectorization to get SIMD out of it. Such trickery is generally not reliable, but [this time seems to be relatively successful](https://godbolt.org/z/11vTbrqzr).

```
size_t difference(size_t n, const char* a, const char* b) {
    size_t res = 0;
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; (i + 127) < n; i += 128) {
        uint8_t inner_count = 0;
        for (size_t j = 0; j < 128; j++)
            inner_count += a[i + j] == b[i + j];
        res += inner_count;
    }
    for (; i < n; i++)
        res += a[i] == b[i];
    return n - res;
}
```

The result from Clang (the important part) is this:

```
    vmovdqu ymm2, ymmword ptr [rsi + rcx]
    vmovdqu ymm3, ymmword ptr [rsi + rcx + 32]
    vmovdqu ymm4, ymmword ptr [rsi + rcx + 64]
    vmovdqu ymm5, ymmword ptr [rsi + rcx + 96]
    vpcmpeqb        ymm2, ymm2, ymmword ptr [rdx + rcx]
    vpand   ymm2, ymm2, ymm0
    vpcmpeqb        ymm3, ymm3, ymmword ptr [rdx + rcx + 32]
    vpcmpeqb        ymm4, ymm4, ymmword ptr [rdx + rcx + 64]
    vpsubb  ymm2, ymm2, ymm3
    vpsubb  ymm2, ymm2, ymm4
    vpcmpeqb        ymm3, ymm5, ymmword ptr [rdx + rcx + 96]
    vpsubb  ymm2, ymm2, ymm3
    vextracti128    xmm3, ymm2, 1
    vpaddb  xmm2, xmm2, xmm3
    vpshufd xmm3, xmm2, 238                 # xmm3 = xmm2[2,3,2,3]
    vpaddb  xmm2, xmm2, xmm3
    vpsadbw xmm2, xmm2, xmm1
    vpextrb r8d, xmm2, 0
```

Which is not *ideal* (quick-bench suggests 1.3x as slow as the version with intrinsics), but it's not horrible. If that's what Clang (or some other compiler for that matter) had done with the original code, I would have been impressed.

This time Clang turns out to know about the `vpsadbw` trick to horizontally add groups of 8 bytes .. if it had known that earlier (when compiling the original code), it could have prevented most of the `vpaddq` and all of the `vpmovzx`. Putting the `vpsadbw` in every iteration (which I suppose would have been the result in that hypothetical scenario) is not ideal either, but at least not as bad.

Comment: It turns out that, with a bit of hand-rolling, [ICX and Clang can optimize the loop to use `popcnt`.](https://godbolt.org/z/qo54erWas)

Comment: Good use of `for (i = 0; (i + 127) < n; i += 128) {` rather than broken `for (i = 0; i < n-127; i += 128) {`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica They’re both broken! On some targets, for example a segmented memory model like the 80286, `i` could be close enough to `SIZE_MAX` that `i+127U` wraps around.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica As I mentioned in the comments below, OpenMP doesn’t accept `i+127U < n`  as a loop condition. That’s the main reason I changed it.  It doesn’t accept `n > 127U && i < n-127U`, where the first test can be lifted out of the loop instead of requiring an extra instruction per iteration, either. In order to split the loop across multiple threads, with no risk of wraparound, you need to nest the `for` loop inside an `if` loop.

Comment: Alternatively, the implementation could use `ptrdiff_t` for `i` and the sentinel value, so `n-127` will always work, although then it needs to check that `n <= PTRDIFF_MAX`.

Comment: @Davislor "On some targets, for example a segmented memory model like the 80286, i could be close enough to SIZE_MAX that i+127U wraps around. " --> Index `i` does not wrap around, on segmented memory or not.  `i` goes from 0, 1, 2, ... until `i+127 == n`.  `i` never reaches `SIZE_MAX`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Good point. `SIZE_MAX` is guaranteed to be at least 65,536 too, so even a language-lawyer is satisfied.

Comment: These are some very good refactorings, and I think the fact an optimizing compiler on portable code beat them is telling.

Comment: @Davislor what are you referring to? The version with intrinsics won after all. Not by such a large margin if it is compared to the code that tries to trick compilers, but that's not a reliable technique and it did still lose after all. If I extend the inner loop to 1024 iterations, [GCC suddenly gets it](https://godbolt.org/z/3Yzbejo64), but Clang and MSVC still don't and GCC suddenly cooperating is practically random luck.

Comment: @harold [Unrolling the inner loop](https://godbolt.org/z/ccdff97o8) produces a five-instruction inner loop on Clang and ICX,, which then gets unrolled four times for more efficient loads. The `popcnd` implementation it generates is better than any of the attempts I’ve seen with intrinsics, and works correctly on any vector ISA. GCC doesn’t do as well, but still matches the hand-rolled intrinsics.

Comment: @Davislor that trick only really makes sense with AVX512. It's not that it's good per se: instead of 2 loads (one of them as an operand of the compare), a compare and vpsubb, it becomes: 2 loads (one of them as an operand of the compare), a compare, kmov, popcnt, add. Effectively the vpsubb turned into 3 operations. And in what sense does GCC match the intrinsics, it's doing something dumb again

Comment: @harold Thanks again for your great comments. I learned a lot from them. Took a closer look at the answer, and I must’ve mixed up yours with some other one somehow.

Answer (score 6):

#### You Don’t.  But, ....

Any modern optimizing compiler is going to vectorize that loop into fast SIMD code   All the twentieth-century tips and tricks you’ll find out there that tell you to pack the bytes into a 32-bit word or whatever are pessimal today, or at best, your compiler can see through them and ignore them, generating the same code as if you hadn’t even tried.

Compile with optimizations on and an ISA with vector instructions (`-O3 -march=native` on Clang, GCC or ICX/ICPX) and you should be fine.

#### Help the Optimizer Out, with `const`

Although it shouldn’t have any trouble with this code, compilers get tripped up whenever they can’t *prove* that nothing else can change the values of `n`, `i` or `result`.  This can especially happen if you have any pointers in scope that could be aliases.

You want to make sure that nothing can change the value of `n`, and that the compiler knows `n` is a constant, so declare it `const` in the argument list.  I’ve improved more complicated loops that way, under conditions that do not apply here, but it will also tell the compiler to stop you from shooting yourself in the foot by modifying `n`.

Similarly, since you don’t increment the input pointers, declare them as `const char* const`.  If there were an output pointer, you might additionally want to declare it `restrict`.

#### Alignment Might Help

The x86 ISA is much faster at loading vector registers from memory aligned on a 16-byte boundary than from unaligned memory.  You can declare an array with `alignas(16)` from `<stdalign.h>`  Some compilers also have an `aligned(16)` attribute or assume-aligned builtin for pointer arguments.

For example, in this code:

```c
#include <stdalign.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define ALIGNMENT 16U

static size_t difference(size_t n, const char a[n], const char b[n]) {
    size_t res = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        res += a[i] != b[i];
    }
    return res;
}

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern alignas(ALIGNMENT) const uint8_t input1[];
extern alignas(ALIGNMENT) const uint8_t input2[];
extern const size_t n;

int main(void) {
     const size_t ndiffs = difference(n, input1, input2);
     printf("%zu\n", ndiffs);

     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Clang 16.0.0 `-std=c17 -O3 -march=x86-64-v4` will generate `vmovdqa` instructions, but cannot if you remove the `alignas(ALIGNMENT)` specifiers.

#### Sometimes `static` Helps

By default, the compiler will assume that a function could be called from another module, and therefore needs to generate code for it and follow the ABI to the letter.  A `static` function can only be called from the same module, so it doesn’t matter whether it follows the ABI or not, and the compiler is able to optimize how it is called more freely.  You might also be able to get the benefits of this by enabling whole-program or link-time optimization.

This particular function would probably be inlined either way.

#### What Do You Mean by, `char*`?

This has a double meaning in C: a pointer that can alias any blob of data, byte-by-byte, or a string.  Both of these can cause problems.

**For Weak-Typing:** Because a `char*` or `void*` could traditionally alias anything, C exempted them from the strict-aliasing rules.  This means that the compiler sometimes might not be able to figure out that a `char*` doesn’t alias a variable like `n`, `i` or `result`.  Since you’re declaring those variables locally, and it doesn’t matter if two input ranges overlap, that shouldn’t be an issue, but in some cases it will help to declare them `const restrict`.  If you work on arrays of `uint8_t` from `<stdint.h>`, that might help the compiler apply strict aliasing and realize they don’t alias some pointer of another type.

**For Character Data:** Characters absolutely are *not* eight bits wide in this century.  If you try to use this code to test how many characters in two strings are different, it will fail.  You would need to compare graphemes, and also to convert both graphemes into canonical form first (perhaps using a hash table for constant-time lookup).  Future versions of the standard library will add `char8_t`, to enable strict aliasing on your string pointers, although you’d end up writing a lot of pointer casts at your interfaces because no existing code uses it.

#### I Know You Said no `#pragma`, But

If you want to parallelize this loop for better performance, the best way is to use OpenMP.  The directive

```
#pragma omp parallel for simd reduction(+:res) schedule(static)
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    res += a[i] != b[i];
}
```

will automatically split the workload between multiple threads, tell each thread to tally its own sum using SIMD instructions, and add the sums together at the end.

#### Prefer Braces Around Your Loop Bodies

Sometimes, in the real world, a bug like this slips through:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    res += a[i] != b[i];
    whoopsThisWasNotSupposedToBeCalledOnceAfterTheLoop();
```

If you had braces around the body of the loop, that wouldn’t have happened.  Most compilers have flags that can warn you about misleading indentation.  If you always fix all warnings at your shop, turning that flag on might be a good alternative.  But I suggest you code defensively.

#### Update: Unroll By Hand

The refactoring most likely to improve performance is to iterate over slices of the array the same size as the vector registers.  On Intel with AVX2 or above, that means 256 bits or 32 bytes (as it is faster to use `ymm` instead of `zmm` even on AVX512 CPUs).

It turns out that the optimizer does poorly with a loop of unknown size, but if you tell them [to sum up 16 or 32 values at a time,](https://godbolt.org/z/ccdff97o8) both ICX 2022 and Clang 16 optimize the algorithm to use `popcnt` instructions on the computed bitmasks to calculate the sum.  (GCC 13.1, for whatever reason, breaks on this version and fails to vectorize it at all.)

```c
#include <stdalign.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define ALIGNMENT 16U


size_t difference(const size_t n, const uint8_t a[n], const uint8_t b[n]) {
    size_t res = 0;
    size_t i = 0;

    for (i = 0; n>31U && i < n-31U; i += 32U) {
        res += (size_t)((a[i] != b[i]) +
          (a[i + 1] != b[i + 1]) +
          (a[i + 2] != b[i + 2]) +
          (a[i + 3] != b[i + 3]) +
          (a[i + 4] != b[i + 4]) +
          (a[i + 5] != b[i + 5]) +
          (a[i + 6] != b[i + 6]) +
          (a[i + 7] != b[i + 7]) +
          (a[i + 8] != b[i + 8]) +
          (a[i + 9] != b[i + 9]) +
          (a[i + 10] != b[i + 10]) +
          (a[i + 11] != b[i + 11]) +
          (a[i + 12] != b[i + 12]) +
          (a[i + 13] != b[i + 13]) +
          (a[i + 14] != b[i + 14]) +
          (a[i + 15] != b[i + 15]) +
          (a[i + 16] != b[i + 16]) +
          (a[i + 17] != b[i + 17]) +
          (a[i + 18] != b[i + 18]) +
          (a[i + 19] != b[i + 19]) +
          (a[i + 20] != b[i + 20]) +
          (a[i + 21] != b[i + 21]) +
          (a[i + 22] != b[i + 22]) +
          (a[i + 23] != b[i + 23]) +
          (a[i + 24] != b[i + 24]) +
          (a[i + 25] != b[i + 25]) +
          (a[i + 26] != b[i + 26]) +
          (a[i + 27] != b[i + 27]) +
          (a[i + 28] != b[i + 28]) +
          (a[i + 29] != b[i + 29]) +
          (a[i + 30] != b[i + 30]) +
          (a[i + 31] != b[i + 31]));
    }

    for (; i<n; i++) {
        res += (a[i] != b[i]);
    }

    return res;
}

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern alignas(ALIGNMENT) const uint8_t input1[];
extern alignas(ALIGNMENT) const uint8_t input2[];
extern const size_t n;

int main(void) {
     const size_t ndiffs = difference(n, input1, input2);
     printf("%zu\n", ndiffs);

     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Edit:** Thanks to Chux for pointing out a wraparound bug.

This generates the following assembly for the inner loop on ICX 2022:

```
.LBB0_14:                               # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        vmovdqu         ymm0, ymmword ptr [rsi + r10]
        vmovdqu         ymm1, ymmword ptr [rsi + r10 + 32]
        vmovdqu         ymm2, ymmword ptr [rsi + r10 + 64]
        vmovdqu         ymm3, ymmword ptr [rsi + r10 + 96]
        vpcmpneqb       k0, ymm0, ymmword ptr [rdx + r10]
        kmovd           ecx, k0
        popcnt          ecx, ecx
        add             rcx, rax
        vpcmpneqb       k0, ymm1, ymmword ptr [rdx + r10 + 32]
        kmovd           eax, k0
        popcnt          eax, eax
        add             rax, rcx
        vpcmpneqb       k0, ymm2, ymmword ptr [rdx + r10 + 64]
        kmovd           ecx, k0
        popcnt          ecx, ecx
        add             rcx, rax
        vpcmpneqb       k0, ymm3, ymmword ptr [rdx + r10 + 96]
        kmovd           eax, k0
        popcnt          eax, eax
        add             rax, rcx
        sub             r10, -128
        add             r9, -4
        jne             .LBB0_14
```

Which essentially just repeats this four times, to optimize throughput:

```
        vmovdqu         ymm0, ymmword ptr [rsi + r10]
        vpcmpneqb       k0, ymm0, ymmword ptr [rdx + r10]
        kmovd           ecx, k0
        popcnt          ecx, ecx
        add             rcx, rax
```

Although this uses an AVX512VL instruction, when set to use only AVX, ICX can perform a similar trick with `pmovmskb`.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Good catch! Thanks.

Comment: @harold Intel ICX/ICPX consistently generates better code for x86.

Comment: even ICX doesn't do a good job: https://godbolt.org/z/MGo9zhz3s All three compilers tested there make the classic mistake of expanding the booleans to 64bit ASAP, instead of adding up to 255 booleans as bytes and *then* expanding them to add them to the total.

Comment: @harold [The slight variation I tested](https://godbolt.org/z/6P8fKxrf4) generates a lot of `vmovdqu` instructions, yes.

Comment: @harold GCC 13.1 does seem to optimize to byte-wise addition and subtraction when I specify `const uint8_t sum = (a[i] != b[i]) + (a[i+1U] != b[i+1U]) +` ... ICX 2022 and Clang 16 do not.

Comment: [Updated link for the code at the end.](https://godbolt.org/z/K51nYPdr5) Thanks a lot for the tips!

Comment: I stole ICX's idea for an [AVX512 version](https://godbolt.org/z/cWfaWfWE1)

Comment: @harold That’s what I was hoping when I expanded to 32.

Comment: @harold That seems to work very well. (By the way, it seems to be LLVM’s idea.) One bit of feedback: if you try to multi-thread it, OpenMP understands `for (i = 0; i < n-31U; i += 32U)`, but not the way I originally wrote it.

Comment: Good to see that ICX can come up with the `kmovd` version after all, it was looking pretty silly before. What's that about preferring `ymm` with AVX512 though?

Comment: @harold Strangely, though, [GCC 13.1 breaks completely on this version.](https://godbolt.org/z/Yr7jbW4rP) And AVX512 CPUs have such high latency on the upper halves of their `zmm` registers that the -march=` targets disable them.

Comment: @harold Okay, while I might be able to get the compiler to accept an inner loop or tail-recursive fold instead of that jawbreaker of a `+=` expression, I think the generated code is as good as I can get it. The one possible improvement I can see would be getting it to use `vmovdqa` instead of `vmovdqu`, but LLVM doesn’t do that even when I inline and pass it arguments guaranteed to be aligned, or use `__attribute((aligned(ALIGNMENT)))`.

Comment: That doesn't matter as long the address is aligned, `vmovdqu` with an aligned address is not slower than `vmovdqa` (`movdqu` was slower than `movdqa` on like Core2, ages ago, AVX didn't exist yet)

Comment: @harold That makes sense. Aligning the data is still worth it, then, and compilers will generate `vmovdqa` under some conditions.

Comment: *high latency on the upper halves of their zmm registers* - what? No, 512-bit versions of things have the same latency on Intel CPUs as 256-bit.   The reasons to avoid 512-bit vectors are reduced turbo frequency, and that the SIMD ALUs on port 1 are shut down while 512-bit uops are in the pipeline.  [SIMD instructions lowering CPU frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56852812)    . Zen 4 doesn't have those problems, but some 512-bit shuffles have higher latency as well as lower throughput.  Other than that, IDK where you're getting the latency claim from.

Comment: The biggest benefit of having the compiler *know* the data is aligned comes without AVX, when the compiler can use micro-fused `pcmpeqb xmm0, [mem]` instead of needing a separate `movdqu` uop.  Other than that, the benefit of having the data aligned in practice (without a promise, or with AVX) is pretty minor, just a couple percent in bandwidth over larger arrays from L3 or DRAM, except with 512-bit vectors.  When every load is a cache-line split, apparently it does hurt DRAM bandwidth by 15 to 20% on SKX at least.  (ping @harold).

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the corrections.

Comment: @Davislor declaring function parameters `const` is not expected to help with OP's goal of "How can I make the iteration faster".  "You Don’t. But, ...." is excellent.  "Help the Optimizer Out, with const" part is ignorable.

Comment: @Davislor `for (i = 0; i < n-31U; i += 32U)` is **very bad code** when `size_t` and `unsigned` are the same size.  When `n = 1`, that is like `for (i = 0; i < n-31U+SIZE_MAX+1; i += 32U)`.   `for (i = 0+31u; i < n; i += 32u)` (with later index adjustments) might make sense.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica That’s a good point on underflow. `ptrdiff_t` might be more appropriate to catch that, or could change the loop condition to `n > 31U && i < N-31U`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica `alignas` on function arguments is not legal C, although you could create a `struct` with an `alignas` array as a member and pass a pointer to that. Clang/ICX have `__attribute((aligned(ALIGNMENT)))`, and GCC has `__builtin_assume_aligned`. So you could write a #define that expanded to the proper qualifier for your compiler and target, or to `/**/` if there is none.

Comment: @Davislor Good point on `#include <stdalign.h>  ...`.  Will reconsider.  Your `struct`  alternative looks good.

Comment: `n>31U && i < n-31U` simpler as `i + 31u < n`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica That’s how I originally wrote it! First, though, there’s the same wraparound bug if `i` happens to be very large (although that could only actually happen on some segmented architectures I’ve programmed on, years ago). But I was motivated to change it because OpenMP choked on the loop condition `i + 31U < N`.

Comment: @chux Ugh. If you want `#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:res) schedule(static)` to work, [you have to wrap the first loop in an `if` block.](https://godbolt.org/z/9jY6WGGrT) And adding `simd` will actually break SIMD.

Comment: @Davislor "That’s how I originally wrote it!" --> maybe not.  Prior code looks like `i < n-31U`, not suggested `i + 31u < n`.  "same wraparound bug if `i` happens to be very large" does not apply as `i` is 0, 1, 2, 3... and stops at `i + 31u == n`, before wrap-aroud.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146604/discussion-between-davislor-and-chux-reinstate-monica).